# Backends logs depth

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a long-running process in a backend and I have seen that the log only stores the last 1000 logging calls per request.

While this might not be an issue for a frontend handler, I find it very inconvenient for a backend, where a process might be running indefinitely.

I have tried flushing logs to see if it creates a new logging entry, but it didn't. This seems so wrong, that I'm sure there must be a simple solution for this. Please, help!

Thanks stackoverflowians!

Update: Someone [already asked](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/google-appengine/backend%2420log/google-appengine/mjOmWHsg81M/YRj57n4m4oQJ) about this in the appengine google group, but there was no answer....

**Edit:** The 'depth' I am concerned with is not the total number of RequestLogs, which is fine, but the number of AppLogs in a RequestLog (which is limited to 1000).

**Edit 2:** I did the following test to try David Pope's suggestions:

```py
def test_backends(self):
    launched = self.request.get('launched')
    if launched:
        #Do the job, we are running in the backend
        logging.info('There we go!')
        from google.appengine.api.logservice import logservice

        for i in range(1500):
            if i == 500:
                logservice.flush()
                logging.info('flushhhhh')
            logging.info('Call number %s'%i)
    else:
        #Launch the task in the backend
        from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
        tq_params = {'url': self.uri_for('backend.test_backends'),
                     'params': {'launched': True},
                     }
        if not DEBUG:
            tq_params['target'] = 'crawler'
        taskqueue.add(**tq_params)
```

Basically, this creates a backend task that logs 1500 lines, flushing at number 500. I would expect to see two RequestLogs, the first one with 500 lines in it and the second one with 1000 lines.

The results are the following:

- **I didn't get the result that the documentation suggests**, manually flushing the logs doesn't create a new log entry, I still have one single RequestLog with 1000 lines in it. I already saw this part of the docs some time ago, but I got this same result, so I thought I wasn't understanding what the docs were saying. Anyways, at the time, I left a `logservice.flush()` call in my backend code, and the problem wasn't solved.
- I downloaded the logs with appcfg.py, and guess what?... **all the AppLogs are there!** I usually browse the logs in the web UI, I'm not sure if I could get a confortable workflow to view the logs this way... The ideal solution for me would be the one that is described in the docs.
- My apps **autoflush settings are set to the default**, I played with them when at some time, but I saw that the problem persisted, so I left them unset.

I'm using python ;)

Answer (score 1):

[The Google docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Logging) suggest that flushing should do exactly what you want.  If your flushing is working correctly, you will see "partial" request logs tagged with "flush" and the start time of the originating request.

A couple of things to check:

- Can you post your code that flushes the logs?  It might not be working.
- Are you using the GAE web console to view the logs?  It's possible that the limit is just a web UI limit, and that if you actually fetch the logs via the API then all the data will be there.  (This should only be an issue if flushing isn't working correctly.)
- Check your application's [autoflush settings](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/functions#auto_flush).

I assume there are corresponding links for Java, if that's what you're using; you didn't say.

Comment: Please, see my second edit above. I already saw that part of the docs in the past. And I tried to do as they say, but I didn't manage to get it to work as described. Maybe I'm not flushing the logs in the right way... I have done the test flushing and without flushing, the results were the same, so it seems like I might not be flushing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think that might help is to use a timed/cron script like the following to run every hour or so from you workstation/server

```
appcfg.py --oauth2 request_logs appname/ output.log --append
```

This should give you a complete log - I haven't tested it myself

I did some more reading and it seems CRON is already part of appcfg
    https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth

```
appcfg.py [options] cron_info <app-directory>
Displays information about the scheduled task (cron) configuration, including the
expected times of the next few executions. By default, displays the times of the
next 5  runs. You can modify the number of future run times displayed
with the -- num_runs=... option.
```

Based on your comment, I would try.

1) Write you own logger class

2) Use more than one version

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that woudn't solve the problem. What is 'overflowing' is the number of AppLogs for a single RequestLog. That can happen in as little as 5 minutes in my App, in other apps it can be even lower since it is only 1000 logging calls per request.